# DataContractSerializer and Dictionary and XSL

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xslt, serialization

Using DataContractSerializer to serialize an object that has multiple IDictionary members. The serialized data has a bunch of name spaces added to it such as d2p1, d3p1 etc. I am trying to use a xsl to transform the serialized data for reading, but I don't know how to create the xsl rules when these namespaces look like they are dynamically generated.

Is there a best practice way to handle this with xsl or is there a way to serialize it without those extra name spaces?

Serialized data looks something like this

```
<Attributes xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
<d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <d2p1:Key>name</d2p1:Key>
    <d2p1:Value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">Test object</d2p1:Value>
</d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <d2p1:Key>x</d2p1:Key>
    <d2p1:Value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:double">0.5</d2p1:Value>
</d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <d2p1:Key>y</d2p1:Key>
    <d2p1:Value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:double">1.25</d2p1:Value>
</d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <d2p1:Key>age</d2p1:Key>
    <d2p1:Value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:int">4</d2p1:Value>
</d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
<d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
    <d2p1:Key>list-of-strings</d2p1:Key>
    <d2p1:Value>
        <d2p1:string>one string</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>two string</d2p1:string>
        <d2p1:string>last string</d2p1:string>
    </d2p1:Value>
</d2p1:KeyValueOfstringanyType>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but it looks like these name spaces are generated when it doesn't know of the namespace. In this case it is the Dictionary. If I define my own class that implements IDictionary with a data contract then it would know the namespace?

Comment: It seems that only the namespace **prefixes** are dynamic, the namespace **URIs** look stable and regular. You do not need to know the prefixes to process XML documents with XSLT. If you are asking for an XSLT solution here: Please make it clear what the input XML document is, show the XML output you expect and explain the rules of the transformation. Do not assume that people who know XSLT also know C# and WCF. Help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the namespace URI as suggested by Mathias Muller works.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have the WCF tag, so you should be able to use json instead.
Use the newtonsoft.json.dll instead since its easier to work with.

If you really want to keep using XML then try using XElement to modify your xml tree:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx